# ArchIso не устанавливаются пакеты в образ

Tags: linux, live-usb

Есть желание сделать кастомную сборку Arch-а. Использую для этого софт ArchIso. Действуя строго по мануалу с вики, пакеты из packages.x86_64 не устанавливаются в образ. Никаких ошибок в процессе сборки не наблюдалось. В чем может быть проблема?

Заранее благодарю всех присутствующих

Answer (score 0):

вот простенький рабочий скрипт для сборки образа где просто добавляется два пакета `fping` и `mtr` в **iso-образ** который собран со стандартным **releng** профилем:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir=/tmp/archiso
work_dir=$dir/build
out_dir=$dir/iso
profile=$dir/profile

rm    -rf $work_dir
mkdir -p  $work_dir $out_dir

cp    -ru /usr/share/archiso/configs/releng/ $profile
cat <<END >> $profile/packages.x86_64
fping
mtr
END

mkarchiso -v -w $work_dir -o $out_dir $profile

exit
```

также пакеты можно добавлять через ключ -p

```
mkarchiso -p "пакет1 пакет2 ..." ...
```